# Application crashes when run from C# Process in contrast to from command window

Tags: c#, azure

I am running a azure cloud service that processes some data with some native compiled executable.

If i run the following in a command prompt on the target machine:

```
C:\algorithms\SInnovations.Algorithms\SInnovations.Algorithms.RawConverter.1.0.0-pre-20140323\NikonRawReader.exe  DSC_028.NEF
```

then it runs with no problems.

if I do:

```
      ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
      new ProcessStartInfo("cmd",@"/C C:\algorithms\SInnovations.Algorithms\SInnovations.Algorithms.RawConverter.1.0.0-pre-20140323\NikonRawReader.exe  DSC_028.NEF");

        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        procStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;

        using (Process proc = new Process())
        {
            proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
            proc.Start();

            var text = await proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
            Trace.TraceInformation(text);
            proc.WaitForExit((int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).TotalMilliseconds);
            if (proc.ExitCode != 0)
            {
                throw new RunAlgorithmException("Process exit code not 0");
            }
        }
```

then the application dont run to completion.

I used ProcessMonitor to verify that the call to process looks alike:

```
Parent PID: 3960, Command line: C:\algorithms\SInnovations.Algorithms\SInnovations.Algorithms.RawConverter.1.0.0-pre-20140323\NikonRawReader.exe  DSC_028.NEF, 
Current directory: C:\tasks\f48914e4-19cf-4020-a7c7-b3150cea0164\,
 Environment: 
    =C:=C:\tasks\f48914e4-19cf-4020-a7c7-b3150cea0164
    =D:=D:\Windows\System32
    =ExitCode=00000000
    ALLUSERSPROFILE=D:\ProgramData
    APPDATA=D:\Users\pksorensen\AppData\Roaming
    CLIENTNAME=LAPTOP-PC
    CommonProgramFiles=D:\Program Files\Common Files
    CommonProgramFiles(x86)=D:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
    CommonProgramW6432=D:\Program Files\Common Files
    COMPUTERNAME=RD00155D871170
    ComSpec=D:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
    FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
    HOMEDRIVE=D:
    HOMEPATH=\Users\pksorensen
    LOCALAPPDATA=D:\Users\pksorensen\AppData\Local
    LOGONSERVER=\\RD00155D871170
    NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=1
    OS=Windows_NT
    Path=D:\Windows\system32;D:\Windows;D:\Windows\System32\Wbem;D:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
    PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
    PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
    PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=AMD64 Family 16 Model 8 Stepping 1, AuthenticAMD
    PROCESSOR_LEVEL=16
    PROCESSOR_REVISION=0801
    ProgramData=D:\ProgramData
    ProgramFiles=D:\Program Files
    ProgramFiles(x86)=D:\Program Files (x86)
    ProgramW6432=D:\Program Files
    PROMPT=$P$G
    PSModulePath=D:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;d:\Program Files\Microsoft Security Client\MpProvider\
    PUBLIC=D:\Users\Public
    SESSIONNAME=RDP-Tcp#1
    SystemDrive=D:
    SystemRoot=D:\Windows
    TEMP=D:\Users\PKSORE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2
    TMP=D:\Users\PKSORE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2
    USERDOMAIN=RD00155D871170
    USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=RD00155D871170
    USERNAME=pksorensen
    USERPROFILE=D:\Users\pksorensen
    windir=D:\Windows


Parent PID: 2748, Command line: c:\algorithms\SInnovations.Algorithms\SInnovations.Algorithms.RawConverter.1.0.0-pre-20140323\NikonRawReader.exe   DSC_1344.NEF, 
    Current directory: c:\tasks\6a94a8f0-82b6-4843-936f-171ff553b949\, 
    Environment: 
    =C:=c:\tasks\6a94a8f0-82b6-4843-936f-171ff553b949
    ALLUSERSPROFILE=D:\ProgramData
    APPCMD=D:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\APPCMD.exe
    APPDATA=D:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming
    CleanupFirewallOnRoleRestart=True
    CommonProgramFiles=D:\Program Files\Common Files
    CommonProgramFiles(x86)=D:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
    CommonProgramW6432=D:\Program Files\Common Files
    COMPUTERNAME=RD00155D871170
    ComSpec=D:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
    DiagnosticStore=C:\Resources\directory\33da8f21b4294080ab4d59d2147b3e72.Ascend.Algorithms.AzureHost.DiagnosticStore\
    FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
    LOCALAPPDATA=D:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local
    NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=1
    OS=Windows_NT
    PATH=D:\Windows\system32;D:\Windows;D:\Windows\System32\Wbem;D:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;;F:\base\x64;F:\base\x86;F:\diagnostics\x64;;D:\Packages\GuestAgent\GuestAgent\LegacyRuntime\x64;D:\Packages\GuestAgent\GuestAgent\LegacyRuntime\x86;D:\Windows\system32;D:\Windows;D:\Windows\System32\Wbem;D:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;;F:\base\x64;F:\base\x86;F:\diagnostics\x64;;D:\Packages\GuestAgent\GuestAgent\LegacyRuntime\x64;D:\Packages\GuestAgent\GuestAgent\LegacyRuntime\x86;D:\Windows\system32;D:\Windows;D:\Windows\System32\Wbem;D:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;;F:\base\x64;F:\base\x86;F:\diagnostics\x64;;D:\Packages\GuestAgent\GuestAgent\LegacyRuntime\x64;D:\Packages\GuestAgent\GuestAgent\LegacyRuntime\x86;D:\Windows\system32;D:\Windows;D:\Windows\System32\Wbem;D:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;;F:\base\x64;F:\base\x86;F:\diagnostics\x64;;D:\Packages\GuestAgent\GuestAgent\LegacyRuntime\x64;D:\Packages\GuestAgent\GuestAgent\LegacyRuntime\x86;;c:\dependency-packages\opencv.3.0.0;c:\dependency-packages\libraw.0.16.0
    PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.CPL
    PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
    PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=AMD64 Family 16 Model 8 Stepping 1, AuthenticAMD
    PROCESSOR_LEVEL=16
    PROCESSOR_REVISION=0801
    ProgramData=D:\ProgramData
    ProgramFiles=D:\Program Files
    ProgramFiles(x86)=D:\Program Files (x86)
    ProgramW6432=D:\Program Files
    PROMPT=$P$G
    PSModulePath=WindowsPowerShell\Modules;D:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;D:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;d:\Program Files\Microsoft Security Client\MpProvider\
    PUBLIC=D:\Users\Public
    SystemDrive=D:
    SystemRoot=D:\Windows
    TEMP=C:\Resources\temp\33da8f21b4294080ab4d59d2147b3e72.Ascend.Algorithms.AzureHost\RoleTemp
    TMP=C:\Resources\temp\33da8f21b4294080ab4d59d2147b3e72.Ascend.Algorithms.AzureHos
```

Where its the last that just stop in the middle of processing.

Comment: At least they have totally different environments. Temps are different etc. Have you tried to set LoadUserProfile to true?

Comment: Changing the temp paths seem to do the trick. Need to investigate and test some more. Seems that all the environments are being changed a lot by the azure cloud service. Will look into LoadUserProfile also